# Async version of AuthenticatedBuilder in play 2

Tags: scala, asynchronous, playframework-2.4

I am trying to compose a basic authentication with some other action:

```
  def findByNameSecure(username: String) = Authenticated { _ =>
    val cursor: Cursor[JsObject] = persons.
      find(Json.obj("userdetails.username" -> username)).
      cursor[JsObject](ReadPreference.primary)
    val res = cursor.collect[List]().map { persons =>
      Ok(Json.toJson(persons))
    }   .recover {
      case _ => BadRequest(Json.parse("{'error': 'failed to read from db'}"))
    }
    Await.result(res, 10.seconds)
  }
```

Route:

```
 GET      /secure/user/findbyname     controllers.UserController.findByNameSecure(username: String)
```

This works as expected. What is disturbing is that I used `Await.result` which is blocking. How can I compose an async version of this kind of authentication?

I am using play 2.4.

Comment: Why you don't write simple example of your code which everyone can compile and maybe run?
Did you try - `def findByNameSecure(username: String) = Authenticated.async { _ =>`

Comment: Sorry, I am not at liberty to show the whole project. `Authenticated.async` works well. Thanks!  I would happily accept it if you could write it up as an answer.

Comment: Your business logic is not connected to question so you could just remove it. Example: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/3821
As simple you write as much help you will get.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`AuthendicatedBuilder` is child of `ActionBuilder`. So I supposed its `async` method should work as well.

Example of usage:

```
def findByNameSecure(username: String) = Authenticated.async { _ =>
```